# when chrony sync time wtih local，why the Last Sample is not zero?

Tags: linux, ntpd, chrony

**Linux version:Centos 7**

**chrony version :3.2**

**chrony.conf:**

> driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
>
> local stratum 10
>
> server localhost
>
> rtcsync
>
> makestep 1.0 3
>
> logdir /var/log/chrony
>
> allow

---

### this picture is about chrony,why the chrony's Last sample is not zero?

[chronyc sources -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmG9X.png)

---

### this picture is about ntpd，why the ntpd's delay offset is zero

[ntpq -p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JAA4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replace `server localhost` with `server pool.ntp.org`, or some other server in chrony.conf ?